# Regular expressions for grok pattern

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I was facing issues while trying to print second string (only) from below line.

### Input:

```
Severity: error
```

And the output i am expecting is, error. Can someone please help? I am new to regex and tried many options and somehow i arrived at this after trimming all other stuff from the line and stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

```
Severity:\s(?<log_severity>[^\s|\r|\n|\r\n]*)
```

Above regex works for my requirement. Actually, I was looking to implement it in logstash.conf file to input logs to Kibana. The full patter is as follow,

```
input {
    file {
        path => ["your input log file path"]
        start_position => beginning
        ignore_older => 0
        sincedb_path => "NUL"
    }
}

filter{

grok {

match => ["message","Severity:\s(?<log_severity>[^\s|\r|\n|\r\n]*)"]
#You can add more as per your requirement. It display in Kibana as 
#Severity: Error
}
}


output {
   elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

Regex=> `^Severity: \K\w+`

Comment: No, it didn't work. I am getting no matches. I am actually trying to implement it inside grok pattern. Any help related to grok pattern is really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: ^(?=.*\bSeverity\b)(?:\S+ ){2}(\S+)
I tried above pattern but still I am getting full line instead of printing only second string "error".

Comment: Can you pass me an example string?

Comment: Here it is
Severity: Error

And, i want only "Error" to be printed when i use regex on grok pattern

Answer (score 0):

You have over complicated your filter. Since you need to match a single word, you can use `WORD` pattern as follows,

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "Severity: %{WORD:Severity}" }
  }
}
```

It will output,

```
{
  "Severity": [
    [
      "error"
    ]
  ]
}
```

You can test it here,
https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Comment: hey @Sufiyan your pattern worked for only for the first one "LogLevel"  for my log----->{"LogLevel":"INFO","LogMsg":" message ","Time":"2019-07-19_03:31:22.252"}------what should I change to get only the values and not keys for this entire log so the output should be like --->" INFO message 2019-07-19_03:31:22.252"?!----- help me please........(My log is in JSON I want to use it for prometheus)